# Java Regex: replace with capturing group

Tags: java, regex, capturing-group

I have a string like this:

```
123456-1/1234/189928/2323 (102457921)
```

I want to get `102457921`. How can I achieve it with regex?

I have tried:

```
"123456-1/1234/189928/2323 (102457921)".replaceAll("(\\.*\()(\d+)(\))","$2");
```

But it does not work. Any hints?

Comment: split with whitespace and remove braces?

Comment: of course, but I'd like a regex solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
"123456-1/1234/189928/2323 (102457921)".replaceAll(".*?\\((.*?)\\).*", "$1");
```

Comment: What does `.*?` mean?

Comment: It is the same as `.*`, except that it is _non-greedy_. You can read more [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do this:

```
"123456-1/1234/189928/2323 (102457921)".replaceAll(".*\((.+)\)","$1");
```

Comment: @sshashank124, yes. Changed `+` to `*`

Answer (score 0):

You could do it as:

```
"123456-1/1234/189928/2323 (102457921)".replaceAll(".*?\(([^)]+)\)","$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

What about a "double" replaceAll regex simplified one

```
"123456-1/1234/189928/2323 (102457921)".replaceAll(".*\\(", "").replaceAll("\\).*", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that:

```
var str = '123456-1/1234/189928/2323 (102457921)';
    console.log(str.replace(/[-\d\/ ]*\((\d+)\)/, "$1"));
    console.log((str.split('('))[1].slice(0, -1));
    console.log((str.split(/\(/))[1].replace(/(\d+)\)/, "$1"));
    console.log((str.split(/\(/))[1].substr(-str.length - 1, 9));
    console.log(str.substring(str.indexOf('(') + 1, str.indexOf(')')));
```

In other case you must be familiar with the specifics of the input data to generate a suitable regexp.